# How to do GROUP BY with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a small problem with GROUP BY and INNER JOIN. I try to get spent hours in incidents group by user, to see that whitch user are more efficient.

In this moment, I only get the error

> 'Column 'XXX' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'

I understand that all of the fields in SELECT statement are necessary in GROUP BY, but if I group for all of this fields, I don't receive that I want.

I think that my problem is because I don't understand GROUP BY and INNER JOIN correctly, so I was trying to learn a lot of websites, but at least in this moment I can't see my error.

Here is my code:

```sql
SELECT
  id_incident_project AS ID,
  i.title AS title,
  companyname as social_name,
  username as tech_name,
  ia.DESCRIPTION_TEXT as description,
  CONVERT(varchar, ia.ACTIONDATE, 101) as action_date,
  CAST(TIME as INT) as acting_time,
  CAST(actions_time as INT) AS total_time
FROM
  incident i
  INNER JOIN incident_0001 i1 ON i1.ID_INCIDENT = i.ID_INCIDENT
  INNER JOIN incident_action ia ON ia.ID_INCIDENT = i.ID_INCIDENT
  INNER JOIN agent a ON a.ID_AGENT = ia.ID_AGENT
  INNER JOIN username u on u.ID_USERNAME = a.ID_USERNAME
WHERE
  ia.ACTIONDATE BETWEEN '## START DATE (YYYYMMDD)##' AND '## END DATE (YYYYMMDD)##'
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. Then we can help.

Comment: Help us help you - please share your table structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: You've rather neglected to specify what you *do* want.  That would be helpful.

Comment: Without using the group by in the intial query .. can you try as " with cte as select ..  select * from cte   - > Based on this result.. you go for group by , having syntax ..

Comment: It's quite difficult because I don't have any structure of the tables. I only can base of another query to make my query. It's for customer with 'a lot of security'.

Answer (score 2):

All columns in the `SELECT` clause that you aren't grouping by must go through an aggregate function. To just get *something*, you can pass them through `MAX`:

```
SELECT
    MAX(id_incident_project) AS ID,
    MAX(i.title) AS title,
    MAX(companyname) as social_name,
    username as tech_name,
    MAX(ia.DESCRIPTION_TEXT) as description,
    MAX(CONVERT(varchar, ia.ACTIONDATE, 101)) as action_date,
    MAX(CAST(TIME as INT)) as acting_time,
    MAX(CAST(actions_time as INT)) AS total_time
FROM
    incident i
    INNER JOIN incident_0001 i1 ON i1.ID_INCIDENT = i.ID_INCIDENT
    INNER JOIN incident_action ia ON ia.ID_INCIDENT = i.ID_INCIDENT
    INNER JOIN agent a ON a.ID_AGENT = ia.ID_AGENT
    INNER JOIN username u on u.ID_USERNAME = a.ID_USERNAME
WHERE
    ia.ACTIONDATE BETWEEN '## START DATE (YYYYMMDD)##' AND '## END DATE (YYYYMMDD)##'
GROUP BY username
```

However, when there are multiple rows for the same `username` after all the joins are completed, this approach will risk values from different source rows being outputted. E.g., if username 'JohnSmith' had (say) two incidents, one on 2019-01-01 with a title of 'Zombie Sighting' and the second on 2019-03-31 with a title of 'Aitch Dropping', then the 'maximum' title pulled out will be 'Zombie Sighting' with a 'maximum' date pulled off of 2019-03-31, so for different incidents.

To avoid this, you can replace the `GROUP BY` with a partitioning on `username` instead, order the incidents, and pick out one per `username` in a consistent fashion:

```
SELECT
    ID, title, social_name, tech_name, description,
    action_date, acting_time, total_time
FROM (
    SELECT
        id_incident_project) AS ID,
        i.title AS title,
        companyname as social_name,
        username as tech_name,
        ia.DESCRIPTION_TEXT) as description,
        CONVERT(varchar, ia.ACTIONDATE, 101) as action_date,
        CAST(TIME as INT) as acting_time,
        CAST(actions_time as INT) AS total_time,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
            PARTITION BY username
            ORDER BY
                ia.ACTIONDATE DESC,   -- pick out latest
                i1.ID_INCIDENT DESC   -- tie breaker
        ) AS OrderNum
    FROM
        incident i
        INNER JOIN incident_0001 i1 ON i1.ID_INCIDENT = i.ID_INCIDENT
        INNER JOIN incident_action ia ON ia.ID_INCIDENT = i.ID_INCIDENT
        INNER JOIN agent a ON a.ID_AGENT = ia.ID_AGENT
        INNER JOIN username u on u.ID_USERNAME = a.ID_USERNAME
    WHERE
        ia.ACTIONDATE BETWEEN '## START DATE (YYYYMMDD)##' AND '## END DATE (YYYYMMDD)##'
) t
WHERE t.OrderNum = 1
```